# In FileStream.ReadAsync we still have to use split logic?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, file-io, async-await

My Current Project download manger tool have code like this(For downloading large files from file share, on shcedule) :

```
using (var destinationFileStream = new FileStream(sourceFilename, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write))
{
   using (var file = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, buffer.Length, false))
   {
     while (true)
      {
        if (file.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length) <= 0)
              break;
         destinationFileStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
         .... 
         ... Bandwidth throttling Code 
         ....
       }
   }
  }
```

if i convert this to **FileStream.ReadAsync** code , still i have to use split file to buffer size logic and download or **this is handled internally by .net ?**

Comment: Stream has CopyTo (and CopyToAsync) methods which you should use instead of reimplementing them yourself.

Comment: @Evk i can't use Stream.CopyToAsync , the above code also have Bandwidth throttling in it. Is Stream.CopyToAsync Support throttling ?